# List of Objects. Find two Objects with same name

Tags: c#

I have a List of Objects. The Objects have a name. How can i find two Objects in the List with same name.
Now i write all object names in a foreach loop into a list of strings and then check them.
is there a way to check same names of objects without write it into a list of strings to check this list?
so my code look like this:

```
List<string> objectnames = new List<string>();

foreach (object obj in DBobjects)
{
    objectnames.Add(obj.name);
}

var doublicates = objectnames.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1 ).Select(x => x.Key);

if(doublicates.Any())
{
    foreach(string name in doublicates)
    {
        //do something with each dublicate
    }
}
```

Comment: `DBobjects.GroupBy(obj => obj.name)` ?

Comment: I love the word "doublicate", I wish it were a real word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use that on your original list:

```
var doublicates = DBobjects.GroupBy(x => x.name)
                           .Where(x => x.Count() > 1 )
                           .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, objs = x.ToList() });

foreach(var duplicate in doublicates)
{
    // do something with duplicate.Name and duplicate.objs
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just group your `DBobjects`:

```
var allDuplicates = DBobjects.GroupBy(o => o.name).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

If you like you can convert this into a dictionary mapping from `name` to a list of the objects with that name:

```
var dict = allDuplicates.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Now for example you can list all duplicates:

```
foreach(string name in dict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"There are {dict[name].Count} entries with name {name}:");
    foreach(var o in dict[name])
        Console.Write("    " + o.ToString());
}
```